# Changing design of variation form on WooCommerce/Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, hook-wordpress

I am studying how to create online store on WordPress and WooCommerce with own design. In other words, I have created html+css layout pages. And for now I need to wrap to Woocommerce

I have faced with a little problem. Products in this store have variations depending on the capacity of jar (the theme of store is honey).

[image: screenshot]

And I don't know how to wrap standard select and input of quantity to my design.
I know about copying templates of WooCommerce to folder with my Wordpress theme. And I'm using it. Everything is okay about title, short description (i'm working with **content-product-single.php** file.

I have something like that for now (code snippet):

```
         <div class="container content details">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <h2><?php the_title();?></h2>
                <p><?php the_excerpt();?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <h4>Price: <span id="price"><?php global $product; echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></span></h4>
                <label for="value">Capacity:</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="value">
                    <option>Example 1</option>
                    <option>Example 2</option>
                    <option>Example 3</option>
                    <option>Example 4</option>
                </select>
                <label id="q" for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity" name="quant" value="1" min="1" max="5">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Add to cart</button>
            </div>
```

As you can see I need to wrap standard select and input of variation form to my bootstrap layout. Could you tell me please how I can do it? Thank you for advance!

Comment: It's simple. Just add the same CSS style applied to the cart form elements.
You can make use Chrome Inspect Element, find the styles applied to form elements.